# C Server run but no output

Tags: c, ubuntu, server

first question asked on SO. Not an eng native so coulda make some error, and my comments are in Italian.
Currently having a problem with my C Server implementation. The code run without errors, but when i excute it, it just shows nothing. I have tried to breaking down the code and placing some prints to shows where it "block" but can't reach a conclusion. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct sockaddr_in address;
struct sockaddr_in local;
//definisco la struttura per gli header composta dal nome e dal valore
struct header {
        char * nome;
        char * valore;
};
struct header h[100];

int main() {
        printf("qui");
        int s; //istanza  del socket
        int newS; //istanza del socket del server
        int newS2; //socket per la connessione al client
        int site; //istanza file ricevuti
        int conn_max = 10; //istnza connessionni massime server
        char request[1000]; //istanza della response
        int primiduepunti = 0;
        int sin_size = 0;
        int j = 0; //contatore
        int i = 0; //contatore
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //creazione socket
        //Configurazione indirizzo IP locale
        ((char *)&local.sin_addr)[0] = 127;
        ((char *)&local.sin_addr)[1] = 0;
        ((char *)&local.sin_addr)[2] = 0;
        ((char *)&local.sin_addr)[3] = 1;
        local.sin_family = AF_INET;
        local.sin_port = htons(1050);
        newS = bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); //assegna un indirizzo locale ad un socket
        if( newS == -1) {
                perror("Bind fallita");
                return 1;
        }
        newS = listen(s, conn_max); //metto in ascolto il nostro server
        while(1) {
                sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                printf("qua");
                newS2 = accept(s,(struct sockaddr*)&local, &sin_size);  //Crea un nuovo socket che è connesso al client
                printf("Accettata connessione con client \n");
                fflush(stdout);
                if(fork == 0) {
                        if(newS2 == -1) {
                                perror("Accept fallita");
                                return 1;
                        }
                }
        h[0].nome = request;
        h[0].valore = h[0].nome;
        //ciclo per riempire gli header; read ritorna il numero di elementi letti
        for(i = 0, j = 0; (newS = read(newS2, request+i, 1)) >0; i++) {
                if((i>1) && (request[i] == '\r') && (request[i+1] == '\n')) {
                        primiduepunti = 1;
                        request[i] = 0;
                        if(h[j].nome[0] == 0) break;
                        h[++j].nome = request+i+2;
                }
                if(primiduepunti && j>0 && request[i] == ':') {
                        primiduepunti = 0;
                        h[j].valore = request+i+1;
                        request[i] = 0;
                }
        }

        for(int i=1; i<j; i++) {
                printf("%s ---> %s \n", h[i].nome, h[i].valore);
        }
}
}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What is this `newS = read(...`?

Comment: This is the perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Some logic problem, look:

```
while(1) {
  sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  printf("qua");
  newS2 = accept(s,(struct sockaddr*)&local, &sin_size);
  printf("Accettata connessione con client \n");
  fflush(stdout);
  if(fork == 0) {
    if(newS2 == -1) {
      perror("Accept fallita");
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Whatever happens you return to `accept` or exits, there is no condition that lets you get out the loop to read something. `return 1` just returns from `main` and exits the program.

Note: I suppose `fork` is a call to `fork()`, but even in that case problem is the same...

Something like this should be better:

```
while(1) {
  sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  newS2 = accept(s,(struct sockaddr*)&local, &sin_size);
  if(newS2 == -1) {
    perror("Accept fallita");
    return 1;
  }
  printf("Accettata connessione con client \n");
  fflush(stdout);
  if(fork() == 0) {
    break; // get out the loop...
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried out, but didn't really changed anything. Still running without outplutting anything, even the printf i placed at the start of the main(). Thanks for the early reply znyway

Comment: @Marco there are also many more other problems (news2 is shared and reused...)